# Unity InvokeRepeating does print() 4 times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have `void x()` that contains `print()` and `InvokeRepeating()`

I expect doing print() every 2 seconds. It does it every 2 seconds, but prints "x" 4 times every second
But `print()` is running 4 times, why it can be?

Source code:

```
private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("x", 1, 2);
}

void x()
{
    print("x");
}
```

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Comment: Have you maybe attached that script to four objects in your scene?

Comment: no, I looked for it through all unity project. I have 3 scenes in my game, Start() can run for all scene?

Comment: I am sorry, this script is attached to any object to scene, I thimk it is because I have 3 scenes, thanks for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) runs forever unless you stop it with [CancelInvoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html) or the MonoBehaviour gets destroyed.

EDIT:
The reason you have `print("x");` many times is because you have multiple instance of your `MonoBehaviour` in your scene(s);

Comment: so I need to stop invoke before doing print()  ? if yes, how to restart it after stop?

Comment: InvokeRepeating is used for runnig a method repeatedly undetermined number of times. From the example you provided you launch x after every 2 seconds. I'm not sure what is your intent with this. Please update your question with the desired behavior you expecting.

Comment: updated, I expect printing "x" every 2 seconds. It prints it every 2 seconds but 4 times, I need only one "x" every 2 seconds. Also thanks a lot for your answers)

Comment: you probably have your script added 4 times or you have 4 game objects in the scene with this script attached